# Test for "focus" on input-element is not working in vue-testing-library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, testing-library

I have a Vue component (modal) that removes focus from an active element if there is one on mount and, in case there is an `input` element, focus the first input it finds. The code is working and I have a working test for the first case.

My test to asses that an input element is focused is not working though and I can't find my mistake.

Relevant code parts of the vue-component:

```
  mounted() {
    this.removeActiveFocusedElements()
    if (this.autoFocusFirstInputElement) {
      this.focusFirstInput()
    }
  }

  removeActiveFocusedElements() {
    if (document.activeElement) {
      document.activeElement.blur()
    }
  }

  focusFirstInput() {
    const firstInput = this.$el.querySelector('input')
    if (firstInput) {
      firstInput.focus()
    }
  }
```

The relevant test part:

```
const wrapper = document.createElement('div')
const initialFocusedElement = document.createElement('button')

wrapper.appendChild(initialFocusedElement)
initialFocusedElement.setAttribute('data-testid', 'initial-focused-element')


const container = render(Modal, {
    container: document.body.appendChild(wrapper),
        slots: {
            header: '<h2>Dialog</h2>',
            body: '<div><input type="text" data-testid="first-input"/></div>'
        }
      })

const firstInput = container.getByTestId('first-input')

expect(firstInput).toHaveFocus()
expect(document.body).not.toHaveFocus()
```

Things I that know / tried:

- If I don't have an input element and remove `removeActiveFocusedElements()` from my vue-component, the `initialFocusedElement` is focused, so this is working and I have a test for that.
- `<input type="text" data-testid="first-input"/>` is in the "DOM"
- `focusFirstInput()` is called and finds the input element
- If I log `document.activeElement.outerHTML` after `firstInput.focus()`, it is the input element with the test-id, so it's correct.
- If I log `document.activeElement.outerHTML` in the test though, it is the body, so of course my expects are failing.
- I tried it with `queryByTestId` and that didn't make any difference

I'm running out on ideas to be honest.